# Saving data into JSON format through Post method

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am using `AngularJS`. I want to post the data in a  file in JSON format to the localhost server i.e. `http://localhost:8080/out.json`.

How should the post method should be implement for this scenario ? OR Any other working example for the post method which are able to save the data in the json format is helpful.

Thanks.

Here is my code :

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
        delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
    }
]);

app.controller('FormCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    
    $scope.data = {
        firstname: "default"
    };
 $scope.submitForm=function($scope, $http) {
  $http.post('someurl', JSON.stringify(data)).
   success(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
   }).
   error(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
   });
  };
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="controller.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="FormCtrl">
    <form name="saveTemplateData" action="#">
  First name:    <input type="text" ng-model="data.firstname">   <br/><br/>
  <button type="submit" ng-Click='submitForm()'>Submit</button>
 </form>
  </div>
</body>
 
</html>
```

Comment: Doesn't `$http.post('someurl', data)`... work for you?

Comment: @OmriAharon: Replaced someurl with the localhost server address but Not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding my comment as an answer:

Sounds like you're sending to a different domain than the one you're on.. in general you can't do that unless that domain accepts such requests.

Comment: It works without error but the value is not saving to the file out.json. Is there anything else which is required ?

Comment: Do you have any idea..?

Comment: @VaibhavJain Does the data reach the server OK ? Where are you trying to save to file?

Comment: Yes. on click submit It was successful but data coming as [ object object ] and I want to save the data in JSON format in the .json file which is again at the location of localhost:8080/out.json

Comment: @VaibhavJain I see. I've never sent to a /file.json myself so I can only offer speculations, can you check in Fiddler if you see  `Accept: application/json` as a header?

Answer (score 1):

You doesn't need to use the stringily function. 
I think you forgot to put `$scope.` before `data`

try with this code :

```
$scope.submitForm=function($scope, $http) {
    $http.post('someurl', $scope.data).
        success(function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
        }).
        error(function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
        });
    };
```

**EDIT**

Oh I didn't see that but you don't need too specify `$scope, $http` again when you declare a function like `submitForm`. If you do it, you will have to variable named $scope which not will be in the same scope and you haven't access to data.

```
$scope.submitForm = function() {
    $http.post('someurl', $scope.data).
        success(function(data) {
                    console.log("success" + data);
        }).
        error(function(data) {
                    console.log("error" + data);
        });
    };
```

Comment: Giving Error : 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined' in the line  $http.post('someurl', $scope.data).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think i am missing something else also because it is giving me now the following error:  XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/JsonData/out.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
controller.js:20

Comment: @VaibhavJain sounds like you're sending to a different domain than the one you're on.. in general you can't do that unless that domain accepts such requests.

Comment: @OmriAharon : Yes !! Thank you. After deploying it to the same domain it works. Please Add this comment as an answer. I will accept. Thanks once again.